# Write a function, iterate through an object and string, return account balance and account name

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I am getting stuck on this code because I'm able to iterate through the object (I have two ways listed below), however, if I need the second key in the object, I'm not sure how to access that key automatically.

Here are the instructions for the problem: Write a function bankAccountChecker which receives an object, which represents someone's entire banking info, and an "account" string. Your function should check the input "account" of the banking info, and return a string with the balance and the account checked (see sample function calls below)

Here is the first code snippet I tried:

```js
function bankAccountChecker (bankingInfo, account) {
  for(const key in bankingInfo) {
    let value = bankingInfo[key];
    return `You have $ ${bankingInfo[key]} in your ${account} account`
  }
}

var account001 = {
  checking: 1000000,
  savings: 2
};

var account002 = {
  business: 2000000,
  personal: -4
};

var account003 = {
  travel: 534,
  education: 1012
};

bankAccountChecker(account001, 'checking'); //"You have $1000000 in your checking account"
bankAccountChecker(account002, 'personal'); //"You have $-4 in your personal account"
bankAccountChecker(account003, 'travel'); //"You have $534 in your travel account"
```

Here is the second one I've tried:

```js
function bankAccountChecker (bankingInfo, account) {
  const values = Object.values(bankingInfo);
    return `You have $ ${values} in your ${account} account`
}

var account001 = {
  checking: 1000000,
  savings: 2
};

var account002 = {
  business: 2000000,
  personal: -4
};

var account003 = {
  travel: 534,
  education: 1012
};

bankAccountChecker(account001, 'checking'); //"You have $1000000 in your checking account"
bankAccountChecker(account002, 'personal'); //"You have $-4 in your personal account"
bankAccountChecker(account003, 'travel'); //"You have $534 in your travel account"
```

Regardless, each code snippet I run, is incorrect. Let me know if you have any feedback. Thank you!
(I've included the tests and the objects that the code should be iterating through).

Comment: `bankingInfo[account]` inside `bankAccountChecker ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the account in the object with the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) :

```js
function bankAccountChecker(bankingInfo, account) {
  return `You have $ ${bankingInfo[account]} in your ${account} account`
}

var account001 = {
  checking: 1000000,
  savings: 2
};

var account002 = {
  business: 2000000,
  personal: -4
};

var account003 = {
  travel: 534,
  education: 1012
};

console.log( bankAccountChecker(account001, 'checking') ); 
console.log( bankAccountChecker(account002, 'personal') ); 
console.log( bankAccountChecker(account003, 'travel') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close :) You just need to reference the object key. [account] for example.

```
function bankAccountChecker (bankingInfo, account) {
    return`You have $ ${bankingInfo[account]} in your ${account} account`
}

var account001 = {
  checking: 1000000,
  savings: 2
};

var account002 = {
  business: 2000000,
  personal: -4
};

var account003 = {
  travel: 534,
  education: 1012
};

console.log(bankAccountChecker(account001, 'checking')); //"You have $1000000 in your checking account"
console.log(bankAccountChecker(account002, 'personal')); //"You have $-4 in your personal account"
console.log(bankAccountChecker(account003, 'travel')); //"You have $534 in your travel account"
```